# Strange web font behavior

Tags: html, css, web, web-hosting, webfonts

I have a website and I am using Roboto font. On my local server font is working, on one web hosting server also but on third where I planed to put website online I have strange behavior.

In html it is showing symbols mixed with letters, and if I change font in css it is not changing on page. However, all the text that is printed from database is showing correct.

Do you have any idea what can it be? I guess it is something with web hosting company server.

PS I am using latin extended font and I linked it correctly.

*** I found error ***

In web hosting panel I changed the php version from native to 5.4 and now everything is working like it should.

Comment: Make sure the server is serving the font files with appropriate headers (MIME type). I run into a lot of problems where WOFF files aren't sent with the right headers.

Comment: I checked it and i found this in MYME application/x-font-woff woff  and another 3 types are lsited in MIME

Comment: I also tried to add this to .htaccess file in root AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff